# I wanted to build an app that can access hard keys button in flutter. how can I implement it?

Tags: flutter

for example, when I press volume up or down button, it will show snackbar "volume up pressed".

Comment: what have you researched and what have you been able to produce yourself - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Read up on RawKeyEvents: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html

You can adapt this code to your needs, this code will print when an event is intercepted from buttons like the volume buttons, but also keys from a physical keyboard (tested with Bluetooth keyboard)

```
class MinimalExample extends StatelessWidget {
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  rawKeyInfo(RawKeyEvent e){
    print("Raw input: ${e.physicalKey.usbHidUsage}");
    print(e.character);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RawKeyboardListener(
            focusNode: focusNode,
            onKey: (rawKeyEvent) => rawKeyInfo(rawKeyEvent),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (str) => null, //print("TextField has: $str"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```